# How to fix Range function in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, matlab

I am trying to convert MATLAB code into Python and am facing errors related to the `range` function of Python.

The entire code can be found [here](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2188-synthetic-aperture-radar-signal-processing-with-matlab-algorithms) and I am working on Range Imaging code.

MATLAB code

```matlab
Ts=(2*(Xc-X0))/c;        
Tf=(2*(Xc+X0))/c+Tp;     

n=2*ceil((.5*(Tf-Ts))/dt);   
t=Ts+(0:n-1)*dt;             
dw=pi2/(n*dt);               
w=wc+dw*(-n/2:n/2-1);        
x=Xc+.5*c*dt*(-n/2:n/2-1);                                
kx=(2*w)/c;
```

value of `dt` is `2.500000000000000e-09`, `n` is `4268`, `Ts` is `1.300000000000000e-05`

Python

```py
Ts = (2 * (Xc - X0)) / c    
Tf = (2 * (Xc - X0)) / c + Tp

n = 2 * math.ceil((.5 * (Tf - Ts)) / dt)    
t = list(Ts + (np.array(range(0, n-1)) * dt))          # tried using the solution in the comments       
dw = pi2 / (n * dt)                 
w = list(wc + dw * (np.array(range(-n/2,n/2-1))))    # getting error here after trying same kind of solution    
x = Xc + .5 * c * dt * range(-n/2,n/2-1) 
kx=(2 * w) / c
```

The Python code throws the following error:

> TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: I'm not an matlab expert but after looking at the matlab page for the matlab range functon and if I understand it correct it returns the min and max value of something?
Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Please post your entire code snippet. I want to see how you are passing values to `n`

Comment: code in  matlab as : n = 2*ceil((0.5*(Tf-Ts))/dt); t=Ts+(0:n-1)*dt;

Comment: code tried in python as:  n = 2 * math.ceil((.5 * (Tf - Ts)) / dt)
t = Ts + (range(0,(n-1))*dt)

Comment: @Svavelsyra Am trying to convert matlab code to python. So i tried using range function of python and getting error as mentioned above in main question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are coming from Matlab, you most likely want to use `numpy` for vector/matrix calculations. Lists in python cannot be multiplied like arrays in Matlab, but numpy arrays can. `range` will result in a range object, which you can convert to a numpy array, or you can directly use [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
import numpy as np
import math

Ts = (2 * (Xc - X0)) / c    
Tf = (2 * (Xc - X0)) / c + Tp

n = 2 * math.ceil((.5 * (Tf - Ts)) / dt)      
t = Ts + np.arange(0, n*dt, dt)                  # np.arange(start, stop, step)

dw = pi2 / (n * dt)
w = wc + dw * np.arange(-n/2, n/2)           # not n/2-1 since stop is not included
x = Xc + 0.5 * c * dt * np.arange(-n/2, n/2)
kx = (2 * w) / c
```

A difference between Matlab and Numpy in this case is that Matlab will include the last value (i.e. interval `[start, stop]`) where numpy does not (i.e. interval `[start,stop)`). Meaning that you will have to use `n*dt` for the `stop` input argument.

Comment: I have edited my main question, do you solution for this question?

Comment: @Lokesh see the update, please don't do weird conversions from `range` to `np.arrays` to `list`, since you can avoid this by creating `np.arrays` in the first place, with which you can do vector/matrix multiplications.

Comment: using your solution for t = np.arange(Ts, n*dt, dt), i am getting output as an empty array instead of an array of numbers between 1 & 308. So can you help me out in this issue.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a problem and here you can find the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57853113/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-float-and-list-in-python-3-6-8

Answer (score 0):

The `range` function in Python returns a *range* object which is itself just a list. Lists cannot be multiplied with a decimal number, which is what you're trying to do: `range(0,(n-1)) * dt`.

But you could convert the range list to a numpy array:

```
t = list(Ts + (numpy.array(range(0, n-1)) * dt))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I tried your solution for the next line w = wc + dw * range(-n/2,n/2-1) as w = list(wc + dw * (np.array(range(-n/2,n/2-1)))) but getting the error as "TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Comment: I tried and list(wc + dw * (np.array(range(-n/2,n/2-1)))) is working fine for me