# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'list' in Python 3.6.8

Tags: python, floating-point, python-3.6, typeerror, operands

I keep getting `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'list'`.

I am new to python programming and am trying to convert Matlab code into Python. Below is the tried python code.

```
import math
import cmath
import numpy as np
import random

Tp = .1e-6         
Xc = 2.e3       
c = 3e8 
B0 = 100e6  
X0 = 50        
w0 = 2 * cmath.pi * B0
fc = 1e9       
wc = 2*cmath.pi * fc
alpha = w0 / Tp         
wcm = wc - alpha * Tp       
Ts = (2 * (Xc - X0)) / c    
Tf = (2 * (Xc - X0)) / c + Tp   
dt = cmath.pi / (2 * alpha * Tp)  
n = 2 * math.ceil((0.5 * (Tf - Ts)) / dt) 
t = Ts + np.arange(0, n*dt, dt) 

dw = 2*cmath.pi / (n * dt)                  
w = wc + dw * np.arange(-n/2,n/2)  
xn = [0, 35, 36.5, -25]            
fn = [1, 0.8, 1, 0.8]               

ntarget = 4

# SIMULATION

s = np.zeros((1,n))             
na = 8              
ar = random.uniform(1,na)              
ter = 2 * cmath.pi * random.uniform(1,na)         

for i in np.arange(ntarget): 
td = t - (2 * (Xc + xn[i]) / c)
pha = wcm * td + alpha * np.power(td, 2)        
for j in np.arange(na):               
    pha = pha + ar[j] * math.cos((w[n/2 + 1 + [j]] - wc) * td + ter[j])

print('pha :', pha)
```

Error message:

```
Error at
    pha = pha + ar[j] * math.cos((w[n/2 + 1 + [j]] - wc) * td + ter[j])

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'list'
```

Expected output of `pha` is an array/list of numbers between 1 and 286, i.e `[-940.7325, -729.3720,......,6.6187*e4,6.6449*e4]`

I appreciate all the help I can get. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation of the `for` loops, and add your import statements? Furthermore `w(n/2 + 1 + j)` would index `w` in Matlab, but in Python you need `[ ]` to index a numpy array.

Comment: @rinkert As you suggested, i made some changes in the code like with import statements, indentation of for loops and w added with [ ]. I hope these are the changes you meant.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems. In the expression `math.cos((w[n/2 + 1 + [j]] - wc)` you are putting the integer `j` in a single element list by doing `[j]`. Hence `[j] + any_number` does not work anymore.

Furthermore, you are indexing `ar` and `ter`, but these are one number (see [`random.uniform`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.uniform)). If you want an array/vector of a specific size, you can use [`np.random.uniform`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) with the `size` argument.

The following should work, but uses the same random values `ar` and `ter` on each loop iteration:

```
s = np.zeros((1,n))             
na = 8              
ar = random.uniform(1,na)              
ter = 2 * cmath.pi * random.uniform(1,na)         

for i in np.arange(ntarget): 
    td = t - (2 * (Xc + xn[i]) / c)
    pha = wcm * td + alpha * np.power(td, 2)        
    for j in np.arange(na):               
        pha = pha + ar * math.cos((w[n/2 + 1 + j] - wc) * td + ter)
        print('pha :', pha)
```

Comment: I tried your solution but this error pops out. Can you please help me out?             pha = pha + ar * math.cos((w[n/2 + 1 + j] - wc) * td + ter)
          IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis            (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices.

Comment: What does the expression `w[n/2 + 1 + j]` evaluate to? Just put it in front of the line that gives the error and print it.

Comment: Thats where the problem lies. Am not getting any output. part = w[n/2 + 1 + j] 
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: Oh sorry my bad, I mean `n/2 + 1 + j`.

Comment: Am getting four times the same float values from 155.0,156.0,157.0,158.0,159.0,160.0,161.0,162.0,155.0,.....162.0,155.0....,162.0,155.0,....162.0

Comment: Maybe make it `int(n/2 + 1 + j)` to make sure you are indexing with integers, not floats.

Comment: I changed it to 'int' and tried executing the whole function of 'pha' but this exception pops out. TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars